# mgcrea.ngStrap datepicker issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got an issue with datepicker from mgcrea.ngStrap library.

Layout file:

```
<html lang="en-US"  ng-app="ftc">
<head>
<script src="/assets/2db3448a/components/angular.js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/2db3448a/components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/2db3448a/mgcrea/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/2db3448a/mgcrea/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.tpl.min.js"></script>
<!-- Then I'm including the rest of js libs (anguvideo, googlemaps with dependencies, etc.
     Then I'm including stylesheets (bootstrap too) -->
</head>
<body ng-controller="ApplicationController as appCtrl">
<!-- navbar is here -->
<div class="container">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
<!-- some static footer -->
<script src="/assets/60113bca/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="/js/controllers/application-controller.js"></script>
<script src="/js/controllers/event-create.js"></script>
<!-- My other js files -->
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried with jquery moved to the head section but result was the same.

The app definition (app.js):

```
angular.module('ftc', [ 'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'mgcrea.ngStrap', 'anguvideo', 'uiGmapgoogle-maps'])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', 'uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider',
function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
// here routing and google maps config
}]);
```

Controller (event-create.js):

```
angular.module('ftc')
.controller('EventCreateController', ['$location', '$http', '$scope', 'uiGmapGoogleMapApi', 
function($location, $http, $scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi){
     //there is some google maps api code only
     ...
}]);
```

View file (create.html)
Here I've got a form and google map preview. There is about 10 inputs and for only one I'm trying to use `ngStrap.datepicker` directives, so the code is as follow:

```
<form ng-submit="eventCtrl.add()" name="eventForm" id="event-form" 
     method="post" role="form" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group required col-lg-6">
        <label for="startDate" class="control-label sr-only">Początek wydarzenia</label>
        <input ng-model="event.startDate" type="text" id="startDate" class="form-control" 
               name="startDate" bs-datepicker required>
    </div>
    <!-- and there is the rest of the form -->
</form>
```

The problem:
In Chrome js console I've got an error:

> https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$$rAFProvider%20%3C-%20$$rAF%20%3C-%20$tooltip%20%3C-%20$datepicker%20%3C-%20bsDatepickerDirective

All others libs work perfectly fine (`'ngRoute', 'anguvideo', 'uiGmapgoogle-maps'`). All libs was installed via composer (the app is writen with PHP yii2 framework).

*Libs versions: AngularJS: 1.2.0; mgcrea.ngStrap: 2.3.6.*

Any idea what I'm missing?

Cheers,
Kamil

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have shown you don't appear to be loading the template JS that is part of that library:  `angular-strap.tpl.js`

If you load that script file does the error disappear?  If you don't include the templates that come with the library you would have to write your own and include them instead.

Comment: Hi,
I'm including angular-strap.tpl.min.js. I don't know why but editor cut the line on posting. Orignal post edited.